# To hide a "dl" in function of a label content in a "dt" in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

i have the following html code :

```
<dl class="last">
    <dt><label class="required">DL TO HIDE</label></dt>
    <dd class="last">
        <div class="input-box">
            <select name="options[40]" id="select_40" class=" required-entry product-custom-option" title="" onchange="opConfig.reloadPrice()">
                <option value="">-- Faites un choix --</option>
                <option value="231" price="0">2005</option>
                <option value="232" price="0">2006</option>
                <option value="233" price="0">2007</option>
                <option value="234" price="0">2008</option>
                <option value="235" price="0">2009</option>
                <option value="236" price="0">2010</option>
                <option value="237" price="0">2011</option>
                <option value="238" price="0">2012</option>
                <option value="239" price="0">2013</option>
                <option value="240" price="0">2014</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </dd>
</dl>
```

And if in the "dt" of the current "dl", the label is equal to "DL TO HIDE", i would like to hide all the dl concerned(the dt and the dd quoted above) .
Do you have an idea how to do?

Comment: Do you have the ability to flag this in some other way?  Selecting element based on their text content is slow.

Comment: what is d1 ? and dd ? never saw before

Comment: @M.chaudhry Have a look at MDN: [<dd>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dd) and [<dl>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dl).

Comment: @M.chaudhry - It's `<dl>` description/definition list.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to do it -

```
var findText = "DL TO HIDE";
if(1 == $('dl dt label:contains(' + findText + ')').length ) {
    $('dl dt label:contains(' + findText + ')').closest('dl').hide();
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jayblanchard/rAww5/

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't this work?

```
$('dl dt label:contains(DL TO HIDE)').closest('dl').hide();
```

However, what other people are saying is correct.  It's not a good idea to filter elements based on text content.  Hopefully, you would have tagged the elements with some kind of meta data before-hand to indicate that they should be hidden.  Alternatively, you could be tracking the element(s) to be hidden in a javascript variable.  Then you could do something like:

```
dlsToHide.hide();
```

or, if you only track the labels:

```
labels.closest('dl').hide();
```